# Proving that a number has at least 3 distinct prime factors.

Tags: prime-numbers, prime-factorization

> Let *abc* be a 3-digit natural number (written in base 10). Prove that the 6-digit number *abcabc* has at least three distinct prime factors.

I know that to prove that the 6-digit number has at least three distinct prime factors, it suffices to show that abc has three distinct prime factors. However, the example that my teacher gave me was this,

> Since *abcabc* = 1001·*abc*, it suffices to show that 1001 has three distinct prime factors. In fact, 1001 = 7·11·13

I seem to misunderstand the concept of a 3-digit number written in base 10. As far as I know, the base 10 system is the 0-9 numbering system. If so, then how can a 3-digit natural number be 1001? What have I misunderstood here?

Comment: $abc$ is the three digit number.  $1001$ has four digits as you say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a simple calculuation. $1001 \times abc = 1000 \times abc + abc = abcabc$.

Answer (score 1):

$1001\cdot abc = abcabc$ is a calculation. In other words 1001 and $abc$ are factors of every number of the form $abcabc$.

It is easy to see that: $1000\cdot abc = abc000$. And $abc000 + abc = abcabc$.

Answer (score 1):

The notation on this one is confusing. $abc$ is really a shorthand for $10^2a + 10b + c$, with each of $a, b, c$ in the range from $0$ to $9$, and similarly $abcabc$ means $10^5a + 10^4b + 10^3c + 10^2a + 10b + c$. This number can also be written as $1001 \times (10^2a + 10b + c)$.

And since $1001 = 7 \times 11 \times 13$, this guarantees $10^5a + 10^4b + 10^3c + 10^2a + 10b + c$ has at least three distinct prime factors even if $10^2a + 10b + c$ contributes no "new" prime factors, e.g., $539$ and $539539$.